# HTTP Post Request: target server failed to response

Tags: java, android, http, last.fm

Hey,
I want to build a simple android app for loving the recent track. I receive the song with user.getRecentTrack and send the data and session key to my method but there is an error:
"The target server failed to response." Sometimes, there is also Error 3 from the lastfm method: track.love: "Invalid Method - No method with that name in this package".
This is my Http Post Request for [track.love](http://www.lastfm.de/api/show?service=260)

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
String postURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/";;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
String signatur = makeTrackLoveSignatur(artist, title, key);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "track.love"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("track", title));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("artist", artist));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", api_key));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_sig", signatur));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sk", key));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "json"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = 
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(ent);

HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post); 
InputStream data = responsePOST.getEntity().getContent();
```

I implemented also a convert InputStream to String method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Output"+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
```

What's the problem? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Content-type header:

```
post.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Here's a [similar question in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362900/last-fm-api-invalid-method).